# Ubuntu filesystem is running out of space?

Tags: 16.04, filesystem

So I am new to `Ubuntu` and everything seemed to be working fine till a few days ago.

Now I constantly get a dialog box saying the filesystem is running out of space.

Here is the system monitor screenshot. Ubuntu is on `/dev/sda5`

I am aware there are other similar questions but the answers seem very technical. Can someone help with this considering I am very new to Ubuntu.

Should I just do a fresh install after backing up the drive?

TIA

[image: Space being utilized]

`cat /procs/mount` output:
[image: output]

[image: output2]

Comment: Could you please open a terminal and type `cat /proc/mounts` and include the output in the question?

Comment: /dev/sda5 is only 20GB. If you have some files to delete, do it, otherwise, backup, and allocate more space.

Comment: @kasperd added the output.

Comment: @mikewhatever I can't figure out what is taking the space.

Comment: @Sid You can check with `du -d 1 / 2>/dev/null | sort -nr`. Just don't post images of program windows, copy paste the actual text output you want us to see.

Comment: @Sid You shouldn't post screenshots of terminal output. Copy the output to your post and use the code formatting option.

Comment: Hi Sid - Just onna hunch, can you list the directory `/boot` and add the contents of that directory to your question?

Answer (score 0):

Try running JDiskReport (http://www.jgoodies.com/freeware/jdiskreport/).  The developer says "JDiskReport enables you to understand how much space the files and directories consume on your disk drives, and it helps you find obsolete files and folders. The tool analyses your disk drives and collects several statistics which you can view as overview charts and details tables."

You could also try running BleachBit (https://www.bleachbit.org) which will allow you to preview and/or delete files.  The developer says "With BleachBit you can free cache, delete cookies, clear Internet history, shred temporary files, delete logs, and discard junk you didn't know was there."